# Is Ghidra's decompilation of ARMv7 strb.w instruction broken?

Tags: decompilation, c, arm, ghidra

I'm currently disassembling some firmware, when I stumbled across the following code snippet produced by Ghidra (the names are already my own ones):

```
void memset(byte *addr,byte value,int count)
                            assume LRset = 0x0
                            assume TMode = 0x1
  undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>                                
  byte *            r0:4           addr                                    
  byte              r1:1           value
  int               r2:4           count
  undefined4        r0:4           iPtr                                    

22 b1           cbz        count,LAB_FIN
02 44           add        count,addr
                      LAB_LOOP
00 f8 01 1b     strb.w     value,[iPtr],#0x1
90 42           cmp        iPtr,count
fb d1           bne        LAB_LOOP
                      LAB_FIN  
70 47           bx         lr
00              ??         00h
bf              ??         BFh
```

Ghidra's decompiler produces the following output (after setting some types):

```
void memset(byte *addr,byte value,int count)
{
  byte *iPtr;

  if (count != 0) {
    iPtr = addr;
    do {
      iPtr = iPtr + 1;
      *iPtr = value;                // write to iPtr AFTER the pointer was increased
      iPtr = iPtr;
    } while (iPtr != addr + count);
  }
  return;
}
```

Now, I have two questions:

1. The decompiled function suggests that this `memset` function will not set the given address (addr) to the specified value, but will always start with `addr+1`. This, however, doesn't feel right and as far as I understand the `strb.w` instruction it uses post-indexing. Therefore - I think - the order of the pointer-increment and the assignment instruction is wrong. Am I right or do I miss something?
2. After the bx instruction there are two further bytes. I don't have the slightest idea what they are. Given that they are not "00" I don't think that they are (solely) used for alignment purposes.  (The next function definitively starts directly after these two bytes.) Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it seems to be incorrect. The syntax `[R0],#1` is called  [*post-indexed*](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABJGHFJ.html): first the store (or load) is performed, and *then* the base address is incremented (or decremented) by the value specified. So the assignment and increment should be swapped.

As for `00 BF`, it is the opcode for the `NOP` instruction, probably inserted to align next function on a 4-byte boundary.